# Explicit command work, while its TSQL equivalent throws an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, scope

Error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT TOP 1 name FROM (SELECT TOP 5 name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name DESC) as t ORDER BY name ASC'.

Code:

```
WHILE (@interval <= @max)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 name FROM (' +
        SELECT TOP ' + convert(varchar(10), @interval) + 
        ' name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name DESC) as t ORDER BY name ASC'
    EXEC @SQL
    SELECT @interval = @interval + 1
END
```

Executing the following command on its own works properly:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 5 name 
     FROM sys.tables 
     ORDER BY name DESC) as t 
ORDER BY 
     name ASC
```

Incrementing the inner TOP # manually and running the command without TSQL will rotate through each table properly.  (This will eventually include a nested loop for Column, and another nested loop for a search within that column.)

That the command runs without the variable makes me think this is a scope issue.  Shouldn't I be able to resolve this by inserting the list of table names into a temp table with a Primary Key of Seed 1, Increment 1 for a row_id, and then looping through the table via incrementing my @row_id = row_id?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe just a copy/paste error, but you are missing a single quote before the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `exec(@sql)`, I think